# How to stop a serious memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, livecode

I am attempting to build a simulated sonar waterfall display by deleting the bottom line of pixels of an image and appending a new line at the top to simulate the sonar display.  This causes the LC memory to expand 3meg a second. Routine waterfall in card is:

```
on waterfall
   set lockScreen to true
   put "plot" into pImage

   put 400 into pWidth
   put 200 into pHeight
   set the height of image pImage to pHeight
   set the width of image pImage to pWidth
   put the imageData of image pImage into iData

   delete char -1600 to -1 of iData


   put 1 into y
   put "" into nData
   repeat with x = 1 to pWidth


      put random (10) into gry
      put gry into r
      put random (255) into g
      put gry into b

      put numToChar(255) into char ((y - 1) * pWidth * 4) + ((x - 1)  * 4) + 1 of nData
      put numToChar(r) into char ((y - 1) * pWidth * 4) + ((x - 1)  * 4) + 2 of nData
      put numToChar(g) into char ((y - 1) * pWidth * 4) + ((x - 1)  * 4) + 3 of nData
      put numToChar(b) into char ((y - 1) * pWidth * 4) + ((x - 1)  * 4) + 4 of nData

   end repeat
   put nData before iData
   set the imageData of image pImage to iData
   set the rect of image pImage to the rect of graphic "BlackBack"
   put "" into iData
   put "" into nData
   if the hilited of button "WaterFallon" is true then send waterFall to this card in .05 seconds

end waterFall

######## a checkbox button starts the display with this code:

on mouseUp
   if the hilited of me is true then
      put "BlackBack" into pGraphic
      if there is a graphic pGraphic then delete graphic pGraphic
      create graphic pGraphic
      set the height of graphic pGraphic to 200
      set the width of graphic pGraphic to 400
      set the opaque of graphic pGraphic to true
      set the backgroundColor of graphic pGraphic to black
      set the topLeft of graphic pGraphic to 0,0
      put "plot" into pImage
      if there is an image pImage then delete image pImage
      create image pImage
      send waterFall to this card 
   end if
end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line at the end of the repeat loop, right before `end repeat`:

```
wait 0 millisecs with messages
```

This gives LiveCode a little time to update the GUI and discard old versions of the screen.